# Go further out, I'm everywhere. What am I?

Tags: riddle, science

> If you look about
>   You will find me rare
>   Try go farther out
>   Then I'm everywhere
>
> Dare you anger me
>   you shall die in flare
>   Ignorant, ancients be
>   the pharaoh's but my heir

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My shot.

> A star/The Sun / Ra.

If you look about
You will find me rare

> There are no stars close to us except the Sun.

Try go farther out
Then I'm everywhere

> but the universe is filled (well, it's mostly empty, but bear with me) with billions of billions of stars.

Dare you anger me
you shall die in flare

> Solar flares/eruptions can be very destructive to our civilization

Ignorant, ancients be
the pharaoh's but my heir

> In ancient Egypt, Ra, the god of Sun, was considered the god of all gods and the pharaoh was said to be the direct descendant of Ra. Also,, in the great pyramids there are tunnels from the sarcophagus chamber that point to the stars that the pharaoh's soul should use to be reunited with the Ra.

Comment: [This guy?](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/olympians/images/c/cb/Ra.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/270?cb=20150623085133)

Comment: @Mithrandir, yep, that guy, but that's not his best angle for a picture.

Comment: No, [this guy](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/The_Winged_Dragon_of_Ra).

Comment: @IAmInPLS, no no...that's his pet dragon.

Comment: I like dragons.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

> **vacuum / void**, however you call the 'emptiness' in outer space

'Cause it fits perfectly the first part. Not that much the second one I think...

Comment: You might want to improve your answer by explaining how it fits each line of the riddle :-).

Answer (score 0):

#### OP's own answer

So [Marius guessed it right](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47510/18817). Marius's answer is almost perfect and is certainly very legit, so I accepted it. However that is not the answer I intended, although I sort of guessed that Marius's answer would be the more likely outcome.

My own answer is:

> Hydrogen

Because

> Elemental hydrogen is rare in the lower atmosphere, including the troposphere and stratosphere. If you look at the upper atmosphere, and even space, then hydrogen is literally ubiquitous. (although still very thin)

Now about the details that Marius's answer didn't address:

> "Dare you anger me" means that humans can actually do something to this thing to induce a dangerous phenomenon. Surely the word "flare" makes the sun (as in [solar flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare)) a very attractive answer, but it doesn't look like human can, at least not in years to come, somehow "anger" the sun and make it dangerous. Conversely hydrogen has already caused many disasters because humans accidentally "angered" it using fire or spark. Notable incidents include the [Hindenburg disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindenburg_disaster), and various rocket launch failures such as the recent Falcon 9 rocket explosion in Sept 2016.

and

> "Ignorant, ancients be", no offense, implies there is something the ancients didn't know. Surely the Egyptians "knew" the pharaoh was the "son of the sun" (no pun intended). Ancient Egyptians are most well known for worshiping the sun, but little did they know that the sun was not a god, but a giant sphere composed chiefly of hydrogen (a.k.a. "me"). Therefore, the last two lines is basically "me" stating that the people didn't know that they were actually worshiping "me".

I know this "ignorant" detail doesn't really give a good clue for finding the answer, but it serves more as a nod to a correct guess than a clue for you to correctly guess.

Anyway, Marius's answer is still perfectly fit, so it shall be the accepted answer of this riddle.